# Colon issue when using XSLT to create Vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, xslt, vuetify.js

I am working on transforming from XML to a Vue.js template.
However, when I try to create a `v-tooltip` component of Vuetify, I encounter trouble.

This XSLT code:

```xml
<xsl:element name="v-tooltip">
    <xsl:attribute name="bottom"/>
    <xsl:element name="template">
        <xsl:attribute name="v-slot:activator">{ on , attrs}</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="v-icon">
            <xsl:attribute name="v-bind">attrs</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="v-on">on</xsl:attribute>
            mdi-home
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="span">ToolTip</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

is expected to generate:

```html
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-icon
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
    >
      mdi-home
    </v-icon>
  </template>
  <span>Tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

but it causes an error because of colon in `<xsl:attribute name="v-slot:activator">`
When I erase colon like `<xsl:attribute name="v-slotactivator">`, I confirmed the XSLT transform occurred, so the only cause of the error is definitely the colon.

Several other articles indicate to use like `<xsl:attribute name="v-slot&colon;activator">`, useing a variant to insert `<xsl:text>v-slot:activator<xsl:text>` or `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">v-slot:activator<xsl:text>`, or `name="{concat('v-slot',':','activator')}"`, neither which works.

Is there any workaround to resolve this issue? Or it is impossible to do it?

Thank you,

Comment: The result you are trying to create is not a well-formed XML on two counts: (1) an attribute must have a value and (2) a prefix  (the part of the name before the colon) must be bound to a namespace. No conforming XSLT processor will create such output (at least not as XML - if you want to create it as text, that's possible but hardly advisable).

Comment: BTW, the entire block seems to be hard-coded - so it's not clear why you couldn't output it simply as literal result  (provided that the two issues above are resolved).

Comment: Thank you, but the result I try to get is actually a part of Vue.js code, not XML. The result is exactly the same code as the one we can see on Vuetify.js documentation. (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#usage) or (https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/v-tooltip/usage.vue)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I kinda self-solved, though it is more like a workaround.

I generate a Vue.js code using XSLTProcessor in JS. By using this class, I can get a DOM as a converted result. I manage to manipulate the DOM after XSLT conversion.

Here is what I have done:

Firstly, in the XSLT code, I added an `id` attribute that has a value of `vslot` (for example) to the `template` element. In short, I replaced `<xsl:attribute name="v-slot:activator">{ on , attrs}</xsl:attribute>` with `<xsl:attribute name="id">vslot</xsl:attribute>`.

Secondly, in JS code, I changed attributes and values using `setAttribute()` method with the `id` value set in the XSLT (and `removeAttribute()` method as well to delete `id` attribute) like this:

```js
var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor()
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl)
var doc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml)
doc.getElementById('vslot').setAttribute('v-slot:activator','{ on, attrs }')
doc.getElementById('vslot').removeAttribute('id')
var result = doc.documentElement.outerHTML
```

And, voila! The `v-icon` appeared on the browser with `v-tooltip` working!